# How can I create a subclass from an abstract class having a generated Id?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I create a superclass (Account).I create a generated Id attribute .the subclass ( Main account)extend from Account.When I createn instance from the subclass , the Id of the object is null . I don't understand why it is not generated .

Here is my abstract superclass : Account

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public  abstract class Account {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
protected String id;
protected double balance ;
}
```

This is the code of the subclass : MainAccount

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "main_account")
public class MainAccount extends Account{
private String enumber ;
}
```

Comment: you added `abstract class Account` twice.

Comment: didn't notice it !Thank you !

Comment: this should work. how does your creation and persisting of `MainAccount` instances look like?